# Fetch data from 2nd array and put values in the array 1

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary, merge

I have the following situation and cannot find an easy way to do it.

I have 2 arrays:

1)

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [FirstName] => Tom
        [LastName] => Siemens
        [Id] => 10300
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [FirstName] => Sam
        [LastName] => Tailor
        [Id] => 10301
    )
```

2)

```
Array
    (
    [0] => Array
           (
            [Type] => Invoice
            [Number] => 6344394
            [Project] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Test Project 1
                    [ResponsibleUserId] => 10300
                    [Id] => 498
                    [ResponsibleUser] => 
                )

        )
    [1] => Array (
            [Type] => Invoice
            [Number] => 6345555
            [Project] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Test Project 2
                    [ResponsibleUserId] => 10301
                    [Id] => 499
                    [ResponsibleUser] => 
                )

        )
```

What could be the best approach to get the "FirstName LastName" from the first array depends on the ID which must equal the Project Id from the second array and to put these values inside the second array -> Project -> ResponsibleUser?

The result I'm looking for is the following:

Final Array)

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
           (
            [Type] => Invoice
            [Number] => 6344394
            [Project] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Test Project 1
                    [ResponsibleUserId] => 10300
                    [Id] => 498
                    [ResponsibleUser] => Tom Siemens
                )

        )
    [1] => Array (
            [Type] => Invoice
            [Number] => 6345555
            [Project] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Test Project 2
                    [ResponsibleUserId] => 10301
                    [Id] => 499
                    [ResponsibleUser] => Sam Tailor
                )

        )
```

Comment: Before you ask for the “best approach”, you should at least try and come up with one of your own. (Plus asking for the “best” of anything without specifying any criteria for “bestness”, makes not that much sense to begin with.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start by indexing the first array by the id using [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) ...

```
$idList = array_column($array1, null, "Id");
```

You can then just loop over the second array and pick out the name each time and update it...

```
foreach (array2 as &$project ) {
    $id = $project["Project"]["ResponsibleUserId"];
    $project["Project"]["ResponsibleUser"] = $idList[$id]["FirstName"]." ".$idList[$id]["LastName"];
}
```

Use `&$project` as this allow you to update the original value which is what your after.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array from array1 with the user id as the keys:

```
$newArray1 = array();
foreach($array1 as $values)
{
    $newArray1[$values['Id']] = $values['FirstName']." ".$values['LastName'];
}
```

Then

```
foreach($array2 as $index => $val)
{
    $array2[$index]['Project']['ResponsibleUser'] = $newArray1[$val['Project']['ResponsibleUserId'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$names[0] = array("FirstName" => "Tom", "LastName" => "Siemens", "Id" => 10300);
$names[1] = array("FirstName" => "Sam", "LastName" => "Tailor", "Id" => 10301);

$projects[0] = array("Type" => "Invoice", "Number" => "6344394", "Project" => Array("Name" => "Test Project 1", "ResponsibleUserId" => 10300, "Id" => 498, "ResponsibleUser" => ""));
$projects[1] = array("Type" => "Invoice", "Number" => "6345555", "Project" => Array("Name" => "Test Project 2", "ResponsibleUserId" => 10301, "Id" => 499, "ResponsibleUser" => ""));

foreach ($projects as $pid => $project) {
    foreach ($names as $nid => $name) {
        if ($project["Project"]["ResponsibleUserId"] == $name["Id"]) {
            $projects[$pid]["Project"]["ResponsibleUser"] = $name["FirstName"].' '.$name["LastName"];
        };
    };
};


print_r($projects);

?>
```